# Antd countdown add html in the format of date

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, antd

I'm using antd Statistic.Countdown with a date format. I would like to wrap each of the numbers with a div and inside there to be said days, hours, minutes, seconds etc. Is there an easy way to do that?

```
<Countdown className='countdown' value={deadline} format={`[<div>] DD [days</div>] [<div>] HH [hours </div>] [<div>] mm [Minutes </div>] [<div>] ss [seconds</div>]`} />
```

What I'm trying to achieve is have all the numbers on one line and the tag (days, hours, min and sec) centered underneath each number. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at source of `CountDown` component [Here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/ae6279a1f1e7af0ba53f0510b3767251042468f8/components/statistic/Countdown.tsx#L93), you can see that it actually is using `Statistic` component with custom `formatter` prop, so right now we can not use `formatter` prop, but since `CountDown` is a class component, we can override the default formatter by using `React.ref`, I've implemented an example [Here on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tzfv8x?file=demo.js), you can check it out.

I think It would be better if you open an issue in antd's github and ask them to add ability to `CountDown` component to accept `formatter` prop.

Comment: what about [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/dao-ji-shi-antd-4-22-8-forked-p4pe77)

Answer (score 0):

In antd 5 ref doesn't work anymore. So I found another solution. It's not perfect, but enough for me:

```
const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState<number>(0);

const getFormat = () => {
  if (!currentTime) return 'D [days] H [hours] m [mins] s [secs]';

  const days = Math.floor(currentTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  const hours = Math.floor((currentTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  const minutes = Math.floor((currentTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  const seconds = Math.floor((currentTime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  const suffix = (v: Number) => (v !== 1 ? 's' : '');

  const showDays = Boolean(days) ? `D [day${suffix(days)}]` : '';
  const showHours = Boolean(hours) ? `H [hour${suffix(hours)}]` : '';
  const showMins = Boolean(minutes) ? `m [minute${suffix(minutes)}]` : '';
  const showSecs = Boolean(!days && !hours) ? `s [second${suffix(seconds)}]` : '';

  return `${showDays} ${showHours} ${showMins} ${showSecs}`;
};

const onCountdownChange = value => setCurrentTime(value);

<Countdown
  value={new Date(data.expires_at).getTime()}
  format={getFormat()}
  onChange={onCountdownChange}
/>
```